# Fixed element below fixed element without JS

Tags: css

Is there any way to put a fixed element below another fixed element (which height is not specified - it is determined by size of the text inside it) wihout using Javascript?

For example:

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>

#1
{
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}

#2
{
   position:fixed;
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
}
```

So how to put #2 below #1 without `$('#2').css({'top':$('#1').outerHeight()});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your two divs inside another container div and set that one as fixed.