# Position a fixed element below another fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two fixed elements, one of which can either have
`display: block` or `display: none`. The other fixed element is always going to be visible. I want the elements to stick to the top of the website, while having them not overlay each other.

**The only proposed solution I found is in these questions:**

[How to position a fixed div under another fixed div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035230/how-to-position-a-fixed-div-under-another-fixed-div)

[Fixed element below fixed element without JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899776/fixed-element-below-fixed-element-without-js)

> Put your two divs inside another container div and set that one as
>   fixed.

I can't do that however, as both of these elements are on different positions in the code, which I am not able to change.

Here's a code snippet demonstrating my problem:

```css
nav,
.secondmenu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 120px;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.secondmenu {
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondmenu">Might be there or not and overlays the other navigation</div>
<div>Some other stuff separating the two from each other with relative position</div>
<nav></nav>
```

**What I want and things to keep in mind:**

- If both elements are visible, they should be fixed on top of the page, while one is below the other
- If only the second element is visible, I want the second one to be fixed at the top of the page
- The first element can change its visibility using inline styles (`display:none` <-> `display:block`, even without reloading the website)
- Javascript/Jquery solutions are fine

Comment: If the elements actually are siblings in the DOM, and the display of the first element was toggled by something like a class dynamically set/removed via JavaScript, then the rest of this could be handled in CSS alone, using the general sibling combinator `~`

Comment: @misorude the display of the first element is toggled by inline styling sadly. That's a neat idea though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could bo done adding a 'top' with the height of the first nav to the second, like i did here.

Note: This is not the complete solution: If you want to show the second nav only you could do this using js by setting the 'top' back to 0.

```css
nav,
.secondmenu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 120px;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.secondmenu {
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 120px;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondmenu">Might be there or not and overlays the other navigation</div>
<div>Some other stuff separating the two from each other with relative position</div>
<nav></nav>
```

Comment: I mean, I originally intended the second menu to be at the top, but I forgot to specify that in the question and having it below the first one works just as well. So I guess this is the correct solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a holder for both of them is the proper approach.
But in your case you can position both of them **fixed**.
and when the other one is hidden or shown you can handled both elements style(i.e. top and left properties) via Javascript

Try like below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Sticky Kit? http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

Sticky-kit provides an easy way to attach elements to the page when the user scrolls such that the element is always visible.